How to write a professional email to my publisher?
I'm a new writer dealing with a publishing house. It's been a couple of months since we last exchanged an email about edits. I'm thinking that we are towards the end period and getting ready for a publishing date but not sure how to sound professional when asking what their expected timeline/deadline is.

Just be straightforward and clear. Something like:

Dear Whoever, I realize I forgot to ask you: Could you let me know what the planned release date is? Yours, Taylor C.

